Limit of $\sin^n(n)$
Lately I thought about these limits:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^n(n),\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^n(n)$$
Intuitively, I would say that they do not exist, but I wasn't able to prove it rigorously. Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT. No, the answer suggested does not answer my question, for two reasons: first, it's about convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin^nn$$
and, to prove that is does not converge, it is sufficient to show that, if the limit exists, it does not equal $0$. Hence, the answer only proves that, but doesn't prove that the limit doesn't exist (which would be done by proving the existence of a subsequence converging to $0$.) Secondly, I don't understand the proof provided anyway, I don't know if it's because it's written in a not very clear way or if it's me. Either way, it definitely doesn't answer my question.

$f^n = f \circ \cdots \circ f$ here? (At least this would make the question a bit more funny.)

If they existed, the only plausible values for the limits would be $0$.

@MartinBrandenburg no, sorry. $\sin^nn=[\sin n]^n$ here. Now I'm also interested in the other interpretation of the question, though.

@Henry how so? Can you provide some kind of proof?

I am quite clear that you intend the limit to be the limit of a sequence $a_n:=(\sin n)^n$, and not the limit of a function $f(x):=(\sin x)^x$. But your question is attracting answers which are a bout limits of real functions, not limits of sequences: so can you make it absolutely clear by editing the question?

@Elvis The main argument is that in a sense about a quarter of $\sin(n)^n$ are negative and three quarters are positive.

@Elvis In addition, there are an infinite values of $n$ which are within any given $\epsilon$ of  a multiple of $\pi$ and continued fractions will find you some of them, so the sine is close to $0$ and raising this to a power gets even closer to $0$: for example $333\approx 106\pi -0.009$ so $|\sin(333)|< 0.009$ and thus $\left|\sin(333)^{333}\right| < 10^{-666}$ and in  fact $\sin(333)^{333} \approx -7 \times 10^{684}$. But though $0$ is the only plausible potential limit, this does not mean it is the limit: for example $\sin(50044)^{50044} > 0.999$.

Your question is already answered here. The key fact is Dirichlet approximation theorem (look at the proof by pigeonhole principle there).
Let me do the $(\cos(n))^n$ case. The idea is that if we have many pairs $(p,q)$ such that $\dfrac{p}{q}$ is very close to $\pi$, then $p$ is very close to $q\pi$, so $\cos(p)$ is very close to $\cos(q\pi)$ which is $\pm 1$, and if it's really close to $1$ then $(\cos(p))^p$ would still be fairly close to $1$.
In detail, by Dirichlet approximation theoerm there are infinitely many pairs $(p,q)$ of coprime integers satisfying $|\dfrac{p}{q}-\pi|\leq\dfrac{1}{q^2}$, in other words $|p-q\pi|\leq\dfrac{1}{q}$. Say $q$ is even so $\cos(x+q\pi)=\cos(x)$. Using the inequality $\cos(x)\geq 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ we have
$$\cos(p)=\cos(p-q\pi+q\pi)=\cos(p-q\pi)\geq 1-|p-q\pi|^2\geq 1-\dfrac{1}{q^2}$$
and therefore
$$(\cos(p))^p\geq\left(1-\frac{1}{q^2}\right)^p\geq\left(1-\frac{1}{q^2}\right)^{q\pi-\frac{1}{q}}$$
It is not hard to see that $\left(1-\frac{1}{q^2}\right)^{q\pi-\frac{1}{q}}$ tends to $1$. The case when $q$ is odd is similar ($\cos(p)$ would be close to $-1$). Since either the even case or the odd case has to happen infinitely many times, there is a subsequence of $(\cos(n))^n$ that tends to either $1$ or $-1$. Now clearly there also exists a subsequence that tends to zero, so the sequence diverges.

For the last step: are we basically letting $p=p_n$ and $q=q_n$ and taking the limit of both sides as $n\to\infty$?

@Elvis There exist infinitely many coprime pairs $(p,q)$ satisfying the last inequality, so take a sequence $(p_n,q_n)$ such that $q_n\rightarrow\infty$ (exercise: this is possible). Then $(\cos p_n)^{p_n}\rightarrow 1$

Thanks. Another question (this is actually about basic algebra lol): you take no issue in squaring both sides or raising both sides of an inequality to the $p$. What assures that the direction of the inequality is preserved, in general?

@Elvis $p>0$ so the function $x^p$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. If $0<x<y$ then $x^p<y^p$

Sure, but what tells you that $\cos p>0$?

@Elvis $\cos p\geq 1-\frac{1}{q^2}\geq 0$

Oh, true lol. One last question: can you justify the last sentence of your answer? Intuitively it's utterly obvious that such subsequence exists, but how do you formally show it?

I can't come up with an explicit sequence off the top of my head. A slightly roundabout way is this: the set ${n \mod 2\pi:n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi)$, see for example this, which implies ${\cos(n):n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. So there definitely exist infinitely many $n$ for which $|\cos(n)|<1/2$, and then $\cos(n)^n$ would be close to zero

Is the following proof valid? Since ${\cos n:n\in\Bbb N}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ there exist infinitely many $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $0<\cos m<1/n\implies0<\cos^mm<1/n^m\le1/n$. Thus, the subsequence $\cos^mm$ must approach $0$, being $<1/n$, which approaches $0$.

@Elvis What you want is $\cos^m m<1/n^m$, not $\cos^m m<1/n$, and then you let $m$ (rather than $n$) go to infinity. You might as well fix $n=2$, which is what my last sentence meant

Why though? I take $m=m_n>n$. Clearly $m_n\to\infty$, so I can take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

If you mean $m_n$ is some $m$ such that $0<\cos m<1/n$ then this does work. I thought you meant all the $m$'s are for the same $n$

Oh, no, I meant creating a sequence $m_n$ such that $m_n>n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Thank you, by the way.

Hey, sorry, I have another question. How do you justify the inequality $\left(1-\frac1{q^2}\right)^p\ge\left(1-\frac1{q^2}\right)^{q\pi-\frac1q}$? Why did you drop the absolute value?

@Elvis $|p-q\pi|<\frac{1}{q}\Rightarrow p-q\pi>-\frac{1}{q}\Rightarrow p>q\pi-\frac{1}{q}$

Thanks, I understand now.

See, let's take the examples one by one. That is let's first assume the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$$
Now, we all know that $$-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$$
Therefore $$-1\leq \lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x)\leq 1$$
Now, here lies the twist. Please try to understand carefully.
We all know that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{n}$$ is $=0$ when $0<x<1$
And $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{n}$$ is undefined when $-1<x<0$
Why undefined because you can't predict the sign between $+$ and $-$ at $n\to \infty$.
Therefore $$\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$$ is equal to $0$ for $0<\sin(x)<1$.
And $$\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$$ is equal to undefined for
$-1\leq\sin(x)<0$.
Because you can't predict the sign between $+$ and $-$
Because, we all know about the example $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Here for $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ at $x=0$, the value is predictable for $(1+x)$. So, we can apply the calculations for $1^{\infty}$.
But for $$\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$$ the value is not predictable at $x=\infty$ because we can't say directly that $\sin(\infty)=1$
But if, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$$ is of the form of $1^{\infty}$, when $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x)=1$ then apply this rule :
If $$L=f(x)^{g(x)}$$ where $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\infty$ at any approaching value of $x$, then we can say that
$$L=e^{g(x)[f(x)-1]}×\lim_{x\to k}f(x)$$
Where $k$ is the Approaching value for which $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\infty$
Try for $[\cos(x)]^{x}$ by the same process.

The question is, I am sure, about the sequence $(\sin n)^n$ and not the function $(\sin x)^x$ so your "answer" won't work.

But the question is mainly on limit. I think the OP wants a detailed review on both of these limits

"The limit" for the sequence might well exist with out the limit for the function existing.

How ? @ancientmathematician. Because $\lim_{x\to \infty}[\sin(x)]^{x}$ is undefined for $-1\leq x<0$

Yes, but that does not prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin n)^n$ is undefined.

That's what I mentioned. It's both defined as well as undefined @ancientmathematician

If a sum does not converge, it does not imply that $\lim\limits_{n→∞} T_n$ is not zero.
The limit $\sin^n(n)$ as $n$ tends to infinity does not exist. To understand that we need to understand limits intuitively, particularly where the input tends to infinity. I think of it as "as we put higher and higher values of $n$, the function should tend to a certain constant value and the change in the value of output should be in degree(s) of $n$ which are less than zero."
Simply put if $\lim\limits_{n→∞} f(n)$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{n→∞} f '(n) = 0$.
In the given function, the derivative varies periodically so the limit does not exist.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Where did I say that a sum not converging implies that the limit is nonzero? Also, you can't take the derivative here. $n$ is a natural number.

I will start by focusing on $\sin^n(n)$ and leave the cosine case to you. Consider the subsequence where $n =\pi m$ where $m$ is an integer. Then we have that:
$$ \sin^n(n) = (0)^{\pi m} =0 $$
Now consider the subsequence where $n = \pi/2 + 2\pi \ell$. In this case:
$$ \sin^n(n) = (1)^{\pi/2 + 2\pi \ell} =1 $$
Now because these two subsequences converge to different values the limit does not exist.

OP most likely wants $n\to\infty$ with $n$ an integer though, so taking $n=\pi m$ is not valid, meaning this argument doesn't work
